# How to save user data from a get route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am unsure how to tackle this problem or what the common practice is for doing this.

I am creating a bit.ly clone for a learning project and need to collect a user's ip address and referrer link before I route them to the original url. Here is my current get route:

```
 router.get('/:custom_url', function(req,res){
  var link = req.params.custom_url;

    var hostUrl = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + '/';

  models.Links.findOne({$or:[{'random_url': link},{'short_url':link}]}, function(err, link){
    res.redirect(link.original_url);
  });
```

The get Route works perfect. I am struggling grabbing information such as the 'req.ip' and creating a visitor, or even adding another visit/click to that links total tally.

Now, I added a post route for the same route:

```
 router.post('/:custom_url', function(req,res){
  var visitor = new models.Visitors({ip_address: req.ip, referer: req.headers.referer });
  });
 visitor.save();
});
```

I thought this would perform both actions at the same time. Unfortunately it did not and the new Visitor is not being created in my post route.

How else can I collect the user data, save it to the database, and redirect the user to their destination url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need a extra post route. I think you should merge them both into `get` url:

```
router.get('/:custom_url', function(req,res){
  var link = req.params.custom_url;
  var hostUrl = req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + '/';
  models.Links.findOne({$or:[{'random_url': link},{'short_url':link}]}, function(err, link){
    res.redirect(link.original_url);
  });
  var visitor = new models.Visitors({ip_address: req.ip, referer: req.headers.referer });
  visitor.save();
});
```

`get` and `post` are the [http methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). Whenever a request is made, it's only with one of the methods, not two. So if the method of the request was get, only the callback for `GET /:custom_url` will be called.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty cool. I never knew you can update a database with a 'GET' request. I always thought you could only update or create a new entity using POST.  Is this an acceptable practice to use a GET in this situation?

Comment: You can do anything you want in the GET but you might want to be a bit smarter about inserting entries in the database rather than just blindly inserting one for every visit. Your database can easily be brought down to its knee by someone who can just write a simple script to hit your server with a GET method in infinite loop.

Comment: Good Point @Ben.  What would be a better way of handling this then? Let's say from my bitly generator they created a facebook link and it looks like www.bit.fyh4i. Now they post it on a blog. Now I want to track any ip-address that ever clicks that link.  I am not sure of an alternative on how else to track that besides getting the data whenever the user clicks it. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: @HelloWorld: Since you need to track every user click, what you're doing there is good.  One thing I can see it can be improved is instead of just insert a visitor entry every time, Insert only when user is coming from different IP.  If the click is coming from a same IP, just increment the count (add count to your Visitors collection and set it to 1 for the initial insert).  So the logic would be: check to see if there is an entry of IP + referer in Visitors, if there is, just increment the count.  Otherwise, do insert. This will prevent duplicate entries in DB